# c++ format unordered map with fmt::join

Tags: c++, fmt

I'm trying to create a `libfmt` `formatter` for a `std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo>` using `fmt::join` but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Foo{
  int a;
};

using FooPair = std::pair<std::string, Foo>;
using FooMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo>;


namespace fmt{

template <>
struct formatter<Foo> {
  template <typename ParseContext>
  constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) {
    return ctx.begin();
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const Foo& f, FormatContext& ctx) {
    return format_to(ctx.out(), "\n    {}", f.a);
  }
};

template <>
struct formatter<FooPair> {
  template <typename ParseContext>
  constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) {
    return ctx.begin();
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const FooPair& fp, FormatContext& ctx) {
    return format_to(ctx.out(), "\n  {}{}", fp.first, fp.second);
  }
};


template <>
struct formatter<FooMap> {
  template <typename ParseContext>
  constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) {
    return ctx.begin();
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const FooMap& fm, FormatContext& ctx) {
    return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", fmt::join(fm.begin(), fm.end(), ""));
  }
};


}




int main(){


FooMap foomap;

fmt::print("Foo Map: {}", foomap);

}
```

It looks like I'm missing a formatter for an iterator, but I tried defining that as well as one for a `const_iterator` to no avail.  Minimum example here: https://godbolt.org/z/q4615csG6

I'm sure I'm just leaving something stupid out, I just can't see it at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is fixed version:
https://godbolt.org/z/r6dGfzesz

```cpp
using FooMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo>;
using FooPair = FooMap::value_type;
```

Problem is this: `using FooPair = std::pair<std::string, Foo>;`.
Note documentation of `unordered_map`:
[std::unordered_map - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

> `value_type` [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)<const Key, T>

So problems is not matching types: one pair contains `const` for key (`first`) other is not.

So other way to fix it:

```cpp
using FooPair = std::pair<const std::string, Foo>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9KT9j6h1b

**Update Feb 2024**: With newer versions of `fmt` there is one additional change that is needed. The `format` function in `formatter<FooPair>` must also be `const`:

https://godbolt.org/z/s691r16Tz

Comment: Holy freak...I would have never figured that out...thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you don't require format, you can use "fmt::format("{}", fmap)" , review the tests from https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/test/ranges-test.cc